# How to handle null value in Auto-mapper ProjectTo

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper

I am working on .NET Core application with Entity Framework core 2.1 and auto-mapper 3.2. In my following script, I am getting null value and get an error when I am trying to `ProjectTo(myviewClass)`. Now I know I can check individual value in following script by do `userRoleList.select(x=>x.ConsultationId) == null? null: projectTo` but the issue is, its collection so how do I apply similar logic as you can see I am getting a collection of `consultation` records where its `ConsultationId` contains in `userRoleLits`.

### LINQ

```
 (from user in Context.Users
  join userRole in Context.UserRoles on user.Id equals userRole.UserId into userRoleList
  where (user.Id == (UserId ?? user.Id))
  select new UsersWithAccessProfileDataView
     {
       UserId = user.Id,
       UserName = user.Name,
       Consultation = Context.Consultations.Where(x => userRoleList.Select(y => y.ConsultationId).Contains(x.Id)).ProjectTo<ConsultationDataView>() //need help here
     }).OrderBy(x => x.UserName);
```

### model view class

```
public class UsersWithAccessProfileDataView
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<ConsultationDataView> Consultation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you try `Where(x => userRoleList.Select(y => y.ConsultationId).Contains(x.Id)).SingleOrDefault().ProjectTo<ConsultationDataView>()` ?